# Can numpy optimized code recieve significant increase in speed by rewriting it in Cython?

Tags: python-2.7, performance, numpy, cython

I have some python code doing numerical computations on 2d and 3d numpy arrays. The code is optimized in the way that it is not using any for loops, only numpy operations. All operations are done on `float` types.

These are the numpy operations used: `numpy.zeros`, `numpy.reshape`, `numpy.where`, `numpy.logical_or.reduce`, `numpy.put`, `numpy.add`, `numpy.subtract`, `numpy.true_devide`, `numpy.rint`

I ran some tests and the overhead lies within the `numpy.where`, `numpy.put` and `numpy.rint`operations.

My question is, since I already optimized the code in the sense that it is only using numpy operations, if I can expect any significant speed-ups when rewriting my piece of code in Cython. Or might there be another option? Rest of the code is in Python and has to stay in Python. A significant increase would be an average increase in speed of about 20%.

**EDIT1:**

```
# <im> is a 2d floating point numpy array
# <w,h> are the width and hight of <im>    

pdt = np.rint(np.add(pix[:,None,:], np.multiply(depthValOfU[:,None], features[:,0]))).astype(int)
d_two = np.zeros(2000*500)
pdt = np.reshape(pdt, (2000*500, 2))
np.put(d_two, np.where(np.logical_or.reduce((pdt[:,0] < 0, pdt[:,0] > w, pdt[:,1] < 0, pdt[:,1] > h))), self.const)
zero_ind = np.where(d_two < 1000)  
np.put(d_two, zero_ind, im[pdt[zero_ind,0], pdt[zero_ind,1]])
```

It would be quite a lot of code I needed to provide to make this piece of code runnable but I hope this helps to make some sense of it.

Comment: It's really impossible to say how significant any speedup could be without seeing the code. Very generally: if there's anywhere that an operation could be made to short-circuit evaluation of the entire array, or if multiple operations could be applied to values in one single loop, then Cython *could* help (these are just two examples). Please share the relevant parts of your code (or a relevant snippet of similar code) if you're able to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question to provide a NOT runnable piece of code.

Comment: Without runnable code it's really hard to say whether a suggested improvement will help or not.  In most cases you can easily create inputs with something like `im=np.randn(w,h); pix=randn(????)`, and so on.  This will help show what may  work, as long as the sizes are approximately the same as your actual data.

Comment: Study the typed memoryviews page of the cython docs

Comment: It should be passible. For performance Tests it is necessary to provide a running piece of code including representative input and output Test data. Vectorized numpy functions are usually not bad regarding performance, but on larger problems the cache utilization may be bad. There may also be a possibility to multithread your code...

Answer (score 0):

Your use of long lines and `np.put` is hard to read.  I think this is the equivalent:

```
pdt = pix[:,None,:] + depthValOfU[:,None]*features[:,0]
pdt = np.rint(pdt).astype(int)
pdt = np.reshape(pdt, (2000*500, 2))

d_two = np.zeros(2000*500)

idx = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce((pdt[:,0] < 0, 
                                     pdt[:,0] > w, 
                                     pdt[:,1] < 0, 
                                     pdt[:,1] > h)))
d_two[idx] = self.const

zero_ind = np.where(d_two < 1000)  
d_two[zero_ind] = im[pdt[zero_ind,0], pdt[zero_ind,1]]
```

In my experience indexed assignment is fast.  `where` is also fast.  That `or.reduce` construction might be streamlined.

If you throw this, as is, into `cython` you won't get a noticeable speed up.  If you generate the `-a` html, you'll see lots of yellow - calls to python and numpy.  Specifying the shape and type of the arrays may help a bit.  But without loops there's not much the cython can improve on.

Typed memeoryviews can do many array operations with 'native' cython code, but they don't have nearly the power of numpy arrays.

The other option is to rewrite it as a purely iterative operation - with loops in all their glory.  The opposite of good vectorized numpy.  And then let cython convert it to pure C.  But that will be lot of work.